# Dragon Pay Payment gateway extension for AbanteCart

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, shopping-cart

Here is the link of developer section of Dragonpay payment gateway which shows way of integrating to the ecommerce website. But I am not getting the right way that how can I do it

http://www.dragonpay.ph/developers

I want to integrate this gateway in my Abantecart based website. If Any body could help creating extension for it or showing me the way to get it done...that will be of great help.

I want it done in php

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the same files of the Cash on Delivery plugin which is already present in AbanteCart. Make Changes to XML and replace Cash On delivery with Dragonpay. Then in place of defaultcod.tpl create your own dragonpay.tpl file. Add in this file the form with your button (Pay with dragonpay button.) Now go to confirm.tpl file present in storefront>view>defaulthtml5>checkouts and add the default dragonpay php code there. Now you are through.
You have just created a dragonpay plugin for AbanteCart.
It is sort of trick , dont rely on it and suggest better answers.
For now this trick is working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Hi @AmBhar do you know how to do it in php alone? I've followed the code in dragonpay but after payment it says 404 not found The requested URL /temp/index.php/dragonpay_paymentmethod/index/response was not found on this server. Do you have an idea?